# How to add React i18n translation tag inside tooltip.html () in d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, i18next

I've given the d3 code.It is basically a world map which has a tooltip for each country. Now,as the application supports other languages also, the country names displayed inside the tooltip have to be translated into other languages. How can I use  tag inside .html().

---

```js
svg
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(countries.features)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .attr('class', 'country')
  .attr('fill', (d) => colorScale(colorValue(d)))
  .on('mouseover', function (d) {
    tooltip.transition().duration(200).style('opacity', 1);
    tooltip
      .html(
        `<div class= "tooltip_box">
    <Translation>
    {(t, { i18n }) => (
    <h4 class="tooltip_country">{t("page1:page1.countries."+CON)}</h4>
    )}
    </Translation>
    </div>`
      )
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 28 + 'px');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function (d) {
    tooltip.transition().duration(300).style('opacity', 0);
  });
```

Comment: We use a separate json that is imported into the file that contains the translations. Do you happen to have a function or method made to look for keys value pairs and choice what is used dependent on the choice language?

Comment: Yes, I have a seperate JSON which would have data for various countries. However, I am using <Translate> for fetching the data.For example, I pass country code, say "CON", it fetches me the name of the country which has code "CON" assigned to it

Comment: How is your code related to React? where this d3 calls are called?